# Index out of bound error in CPLEX OPL

Tags: cplex, opl

```
forall(j in J, c in C, p in P)   
sum(i in I)X[i][j][c][p]+sum(r in R)F[r][j][c][p-1]+r1[c]*sum(m in 
M)A[m][j][p-1]-r1[c]*sum(k in K)Y[j][k][p]==0;
```

In the above constraint, I am getting errors:

> Index out of bound for array "A(1)(1)": 0"and "OPL cannot extract expression: A[m][j][p+(-1)]

Answer (score 0):

Can you at least try to replace this:

```
forall(j in J, c in C, p in P)
```

with the following?

```
forall(j in J, c in C, p in P: (p-1) in P)
```

Comment: Hi, I replaced with the above code recommended by you, But then it is running forever and if I remove this constraint, it gives the solution but that is not what is require. Here p refers to number of time periods which have range from 1 to 6. Is there any other way to solve this problem ?

set10: forall(j in J, c in C, p in P:(p-1) in P)      
sum(i in I)X[i][j][c][p]+sum(r in R)F[r][j][c][p-1]+r1[c]*sum(m in M)A[m][j][p-1]-r1[c]*sum(k in K)Y[j][k][p]==0;